# How to start Oracle enterprise manager on Windows 64 bits

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have installed Oracle 11g on my pc. It has installed fine and everything went fine.

After restating pc, https://localhost:1158/em is not connecting.
The listener is ok and running fine.

How can I resolve this problem?

If I try to start the OracleDBConsoleorcl it pop up an error massage that the OracleDBConsoleorcl could not start on local windows

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the service, e.g.

```
net start OracleDBConsoleorcl
```

The service name might be different on your system, but it usually starts with `OracleDBConsole` and then contains the service name of your database.

If you want it to **always** run, set the service start automatically through the control panel.

Comment: i did that but still not starting the entity manager on the browser pls what can i do again?

Comment: @AYUASAMUEL: Is the service shown as "running" in the control panel? Are you sure the enterprise manager is configured to run on port 1158? And what is that "*browser pls*" thing?